# TDA7052 output DC offset

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm currently working on a simple audio amplifier circuit using the TDA7052 IC.
So far I have been able to achieve amplification, with a little distortion.

My problem is that I'm observing a large DC offset at the audio output, and the IC is getting very hot.

I'm feeding in 12Vdc and the amp is drawing around 100mA, which makes for 1.2W of power. The gain is set to 20dB with pin #4 being driven at 1Vdc.
Here is my circuit:
[image: TDA7052 based audio amp]

And here are the input and output waveforms (Yellow waveform taken at pin 8, with reference to system ground):

[image: Waveforms]

So, the input is being driven with a signal generator with the parameters displayed. The output is indeed being amplified, but it has a DC average value of around 5V, how do I remove this DC offset? and is there a way to mitigate this slight distortion?

I've tried adding two 10uF caps in series with OUT+ and OUT-, this is what happened: (and I'm not surprised, the datasheet doesn't show them in the typical application circuit, nor do other implementations found on the internet).
[image]

Comment: How did you measure the output? What did you do with (both) outputs (the circuit diagram doesn't show)? The speaker is supposed to be between OUT+ and OUT- and **none** of the outputs must be connected to GND.

Comment: Don't *both* outputs have the *same* DC offset (relative to ground) and therefore 0 offset relative to each other?

Comment: Yeah, you need to connect the load between OUT+ and OUT-, and show them both on your scope. If it has an "A-B" setting, use that - it'll show the real output signal.

Comment: @brhans: no, generally they don't (i.e. only if the signal is 0). The specialty of the TDA7052 is that you don't have one output for a load based at GND but **two** complementary outputs with the load between the outputs. That way it is possible to do without the output capacitor (saves money and space).

Comment: Your signal generator GND and scope GND may be shorting out one of the outputs if you are connecting the scope reference (GND) to one of the outputs. Adding a capacitor just makes it an AC short.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany: yes, something like that is also my question aiming at.

Comment: The datasheet for the TDA7052at shows the use of a 16R speaker.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: Pin 4 has a dc bias and is not driven. VTC.

Comment: @brhans I measured the output with the scop gnd on the circuit gnd and the probe on the OUT-. I noticed that it is 180 degrees out of phase with the Input. that seems to be right to me, cause OUT+ is in phase with the input, and therefore the difference between both signals drives the speaker. The problem is that both these outputs have a 5V DC offset.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I never connected my SG GND or Scope GND to the outs, just measured them separately on at at time and noticed the characteristics mentioned above.

Comment: @HandyHowie I'm using a 8Ohm speaker, which is also supported.

Comment: "The problem is that both these outputs have a 5V DC offset" Yes, they do because (a) Each output has to maximise the swing from a single supply voltage (**so they need a DC offset** otherwise you would only get half the cycle output and (b) Each output has **the same DC offset** so that when you connect your speaker between them **the DC offsets cancel each other and leave no net DC voltage across the speaker**.  That's how a bridge output works.

Comment: @Curd someone is confused here. With the same offset on each output there will be no output across the speaker, and yes no capacitor necessary. Assuming the OP has connected the speaker correctly ofc.

Comment: @brhans: yes, that's why I said that the outputs generally **don't** (= DO **NOT**) have the same offset (unless the signal is 0).

Comment: @Curd the word 'offset' usually refers to the steady-state DC level - ie: the state when the signal is 0.

Comment: @brhans: yes, of course with offset I mean voltage @ signal = 0. That is, however, not what is understood by "steady-state". At steady state there is a **steady** signal in contrast to a transient signal (but that's another topic).

Comment: @JImDearden, that's a very useful observation, thank you. Could it explain the IC getting excessively hot during operation? I can barely touch it. That's why I thought something was wrong in the 1st place, but now I'm not so certain anymore, perhaps it is working just fine and it just burns hot during normal operation...

Comment: No - the chip shouldn't get very hot during normal operation but I have noticed that running similar chips above the nominal 6V does seem to warm them up. Check the supply current (quiescent) with no speaker connected - max should only be 8mA and run nice and cool. It may be you have a faulty chip or its trying to drive too big a load. Double check you haven't got one of the outputs connected to ground through the speaker.

Comment: @LeonardoRossi put a resistive load on the output, I'd replace the IC just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a bridge output which is self biased to be at 1/2 the supply voltage. That is normal. The outputs will be at or close to 1/2 the power supply voltage with no signal.

If the IC is getting hot, well it needs to be mounted to a heat sink. Aluminum is fine. 1.2 watts is very hot to touch, so a heat sink is mandatory.

It sounds like you have a perfectly good amplifier that is just missing a heat sink. All of your parameters (100 mA for bias current for bridge output) seem normal and you stated it put out a clean sound, so I do not think anything is wrong-except for a missing heat sink.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the DC offset of the outputs are not "cancelling out" and that's why the chip is getting excessively hot.
To see the "correct" output signal, use the input as your trigger and one channel on the + out, and the other channel on the - out (**across** the speaker terminals).
If the chip still overheats, it could be faulty.